# Left and right exactness of adjoint functors

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, adjoint-functors

I am trying to find a proof of the following statement:

Let $A$ and $B$ be abelian categories, and let $(F, G)$ be an adjoint pair
of additive functors $F : A → B$ and $G: B → A$. Show that $F$ is right
exact and $G$ is left exact.

I understand the proof when $A$ and $B$ are module categories, but the proof I have seen for this case uses left exxactness of the Hom functors together with the isomorphism $\text{Hom}_{R}(R, M) \cong M$ for all $R$-modules $M$. I don't think this can be done in the general case.

I can't seem to find a anything in the general case. I thought of using the unit and counit in some way, but I literally have no clue how to prove this.

Comment: Hint: adjoints are (co)continuous

Comment: @FShrike Let $A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$ be exact. Suppose $F$ preserves colimits, then it preserves cokernels since it is a kind of colimt. Thus  $FB \rightarrow FC$ is a cokernel of $FA \rightarrow FB$. Further any cokernel in an abelian category is an epi, so its cokernel is 0. Hence $FA \rightarrow FB \rightarrow FC \rightarrow 0$ is exact and we can conclude that $F$ is right exact. Would this be the right argument?

Comment: Yes that's right. $F$ is additive so right exactness is equivalent to preservation of cokernels which is equivalent to preservation of finite colimits. In particular our $F$ preserves *all* colimits so must be right exact